# Update JLabel text

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I'm working on a simple GUI. On Button press i want to increase/decrease a variable and update the corresponding JLabel.

class JFrameSetUp

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JFrameSetUp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private int RecHeight = 0;
    private int RecWidth = 0;

    //Here Buttons

    JButton HeightIncrease = new JButton("+");
    JButton HeightDecrease = new JButton("-");

    JLabel height = new JLabel(Integer.toString(RecHeight));
    JLabel width = new JLabel(Integer.toString(RecWidth));

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 4);

    public JFrameSetUp(){

    }

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane){

        //Create GridPanel and set Layout
        JPanel grid = new JPanel();
        grid.setLayout(gridLayout);

        //Create buttondrawPanel and set Layout
        JPanel buttondraw = new JPanel();
        buttondraw.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));

        //Adding Components to GridPanel

        //Adding Layouts to pane

        pane.add(grid, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(new JSeparator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(buttondraw, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Setting up ActionListener to Buttons

        if (e.getSource() == this.HeightDecrease) {

            RecHeight -= 1;
            height.setText(Integer.toString(RecHeight));

        } else if (e.getSource() == this.HeightIncrease) {

            RecHeight += 1;
            height.setText(Integer.toString(RecHeight));
        }

    }

}
```

Class with MainMethod

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });
    }



    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrameSetUp frame = new JFrameSetUp();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Set up the content pane.
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I'm aware, that's kind a newbish question. I think I'm wrong with my Code Structure. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
maybe use an import here

Comment: try to reduce your code to the necessary parts.The rectangles have nothing to do with the question for example

Comment: There are no rectangles. Just variables. And they are the point.  And I did clean my code before posting. So thanks.. or so.

Comment: Please conform to the Java coding conventions. Fields, variable and method names should always start with a *lowercase* letter; class, enum and interface names, with an uppercase letter; and constant names in capitals separated by underscores.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Will keep that in mind

Comment: Hmm, so if i get you right you are just struggling with the updating method, which would be repaint();

Comment: What's triggering the `ActionListener`? Based on your code sample, the `HeightIncrease` and `HeightDecrease` are never added to the frame, nor do you register the `JFrameSetUp` as a `ActionListener for them

Comment: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) point 1: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never register any `ActionListener`s to the buttons...

```
HeightIncrease.addActionListener(this);
HeightDecrease.addActionListener(this);
```

You also never add the buttons to the GUI

```
buttondraw.add(HeightIncrease);
buttondraw.add(HeightDecrease);
```

You also never add the labels to the GUI either...

```
grid.add(height);
grid.add(width);
```

I reworked the code, because your example was messing with my mind, hope you don't mind...

It's conceptually the same idea, just done slightly more efficently

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int recHeight = 0;
        private int recWidth = 0;

        //Here Buttons
        JButton heightIncrease = new JButton("+");
        JButton heightDecrease = new JButton("-");

        JLabel height = new JLabel(Integer.toString(recHeight));
        JLabel width = new JLabel(Integer.toString(recWidth));

        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 4);

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //Create GridPanel and set Layout
            JPanel grid = new JPanel();
            grid.setLayout(gridLayout);

            grid.add(height);
            grid.add(width);

            //Create buttondrawPanel and set Layout
            JPanel buttondraw = new JPanel();
            buttondraw.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));

            heightIncrease.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    recHeight += 1;
                    height.setText(Integer.toString(recHeight));
                }
            });
            heightDecrease.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    recHeight -= 1;
                    height.setText(Integer.toString(recHeight));
                }
            });

            buttondraw.add(heightIncrease);
            buttondraw.add(heightDecrease);

            //Adding Components to GridPanel
            //Adding Layouts to pane
            add(grid, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(new JSeparator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(buttondraw, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }
}
```

I would encourage you to spend some time having a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer's. Problem was, I didn't register the buttons. The buttons were added. I just didn't include them in the code. Because I wanted to post only necessary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the value call

```
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: Why? `JLabel#setText` is a bound, it triggers a call to `repaint` itself`?

Answer (score 0):

Good to see you learning Java! A few things I should point out.

Firstly, your variable names are good, but they don't follow the [Java naming convention](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). Even though it seems small, it's just good practice to follow.

Of course, your actual problem; the action listener you've implemented is on the JFrame. (See how you extend JFrame and implement ActionListener?) This ActionListener should be on the button. You'll can do this a few ways.

Method 1: By adding it inline with your code

```
JButton heightButton = new JButton("Increase Height");
heightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    //run method here
  }

});
```

Method 2: Create a class which implements ActionListener

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void run(){
    //actionListener code here
  }
}
```

And then instantiate an object of this type and add it directly to your code.

```
ActionListner buttonListener = new ButtonListener(); //or ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
JButton heightButton = new JButton("Increase Height");
heightButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
```

Of course, as in MadProgrammers answer, don't forget to add the labels and such to your JFrame or JPanel. Good luck learning Java!

Comment: The `==` comparison is valid as that's precisely what the OP is trying to do, compare that the `source` of the event is the same object in memory as the button that they have previously created

Comment: I was thinking that as I was typing it. I'm just iterating what I was told in college... I'm editing the question now anyways because I forgot to answer the actual question (derp!)

Answer (score 0):

I bet that your program just shows nothing, isn't it? That's because in addComponentsToPane method, you didn't add any component but empty JPanels. After the comment //Adding Components to GridPanel, you should:

```
        buttondraw.add(HeightIncrease);
        buttondraw.add(HeightDecrease);
        grid.add(height);
        grid.add(width);
```

Then, to listen to button event, you should also add :

```
        HeightIncrease.addActionListener(this);
        HeightDecrease.addActionListener(this);
```

"this" is because your frame JFrameSetUp implements ActionListener, so when either bootton is clicked the method actionPerformed is invoked.
As JLabel.setText method will repaint itself and consequently its component hierarchi is repainted as well, you haven't to do anything othr.

Comment: ...because I didn't say that 15 minutes ago :P - You might also like to add the labels to, because they weren't added in the example either

Comment: @MadProgrammer I saw your answer just now, sorry! In your answer I noticed that you added new code, that's just unuseful and maybe misleading to a newbe, as his class already implements ActionListener and just needs to add components to their panels.

Comment: Adding the `ActionListener` alone wouldn't have solved the example code the OP provided - I also believe (and it's a matter opinion), that the code example provides a better base framework from which the OP can learn - sure, they could implement `ActionListener`, but the side effect is, you get a `public void actionPerformed` method which is exposed to other classes, which really, nobody has any reason to be calling - so I use anonymous classes to demonstrate how to isolate the functionality - It's a common enough approach to a common problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer my solution just perform as a charme, the 6 lines I suggested are just enough. Then I fully agree with you about public methods and class responsability, but my thought was whether a newbie should face theese problems just now.

Comment: So did I (6 lines) - I just expanded upon it ;)